# Contador de numero de veces máxima que se repite una acción

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pequeño script que simula una ruleta, saca un numero aleatorio y comprueba con los números apostados, si la apuesta es ganadora suma 1 en Aganadas y si es perdedora suma 1 en Aperdidas, hasta aquí bien. 
Ahora quiero poner un contador del **numero de veces máxima que sale apuesta ganadora y perdedora**, ejemplo, si 5 rondas seguidas sale una apuesta ganadora el contador estaría en 5. ¿como puedo realizarlo?

```
import random
import time

Aganadas=0
Aperdidas=0


bolas=[]
ComApuestasSueltas=[36, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30,16, 15, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0]

while True:
  bola=(random.randint(0,37))

  print(bola)

  bolas.insert(0,(bola))

  print (bolas)
  for x in ComApuestasSueltas:
    if x == int(bola):
      Aganadas+=1
      print ("Ganada!")

  if int(bola)not in ComApuestasSueltas:
      Aperdidas+=1
      print ("Perdida!")#nuevo

  print ("Ganadas "+ str(Aganadas)+" en apuestas sueltas y " + str(Aperdidas)+" perdidas")


  time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Hola Samuel, con "numero de veces máxima que sale apuesta ganadora y perdedora" te refieres al número máximo de apuestas ganadoras/perdedoras **consecutivas** (sin importar el número que salga, solo si es ganadora o no)? ¿O el numero de apuestas ganadoras/perdedoras máximas para un mismo número (sin importar si son consecutivas o no)?

Comment: hola! numero de veces consecutivas de apuestas ganadoras/perdedoras sin importar el numero que salga, así es, ejemplo si se gana 4 veces seguidas el marcador se pone en 4, luego se pierde 2 veces seguidas y posteriormente se ganan 3 veces seguidas el marcador seguiría en 4 ganadoras y perdedoras en 2, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin necesidad de nuevos contenedores ni de modificar tu código inicial demasiado, bastaría con usar cuatro variables, una que alamacene el máximo de consecutivas perdedoras y otra el máximo de consecutivas ganadoras.  Las otras dos servirían de contador temporal:

```
import random
import time


apuestas_ganadas = 0
apuestas_perdidas = 0
max_ganadoras_consecutivas = 0
max_perdedoras_consecutivas = 0

bolas = []
com_apuestas_sueltas = [
    36, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 16, 15, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0
    ]

perdedoras_consecutivas = 0
ganadoras_consecutivas = 0

while True:
    bola = random.randint(0, 37)
    print(f"Nueva bola: {bola}")
    bolas.insert(0, bola)
    print(f"Bolas: {bolas}")

    if bola in com_apuestas_sueltas:
        print("Ganada!")
        apuestas_ganadas += 1
        perdedoras_consecutivas = 0
        ganadoras_consecutivas += 1
        if ganadoras_consecutivas > max_ganadoras_consecutivas:
            max_ganadoras_consecutivas = ganadoras_consecutivas

    else:
        print("Perdida!")
        apuestas_perdidas += 1
        ganadoras_consecutivas = 0
        perdedoras_consecutivas += 1
        if perdedoras_consecutivas > max_perdedoras_consecutivas:
            max_perdedoras_consecutivas = perdedoras_consecutivas

    print(f"Ganadas {apuestas_ganadas} en apuestas sueltas y "
          f"{apuestas_perdidas} perdidas\n"
          f"Máximo de ganadoras consecutivas: {max_ganadoras_consecutivas}\n"
          f"Máximo de perdedoras consecutivas: {max_perdedoras_consecutivas}\n"
          )

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Esta perfecto! Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Me he tomado la libertad de convertirlo en una clase para hacerlo mucho más facil de lo que sería de otra manera. Además, de cambiar la manera en la que llamas a las cosas para usar el standard https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ de python.

```
import random
import time


class Juego():
    """Clase principal de este juego de apuestas"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Define el estado inicial del juego"""
        self.a_ganadas = 0
        self.a_perdidas = 0
        self.bolas = []
        self.com_apuestas_sueltas = [36, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30,16, 15, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0]
        self.a_consecutivas = 0
        self.a_anterior = ""

    def comprueba(self, tipo):
        """Comprueba si una apuesta es igual a la anterior, y por tanto consecutiva"""
        if self.a_anterior == tipo:
            self.a_consecutivas += 1
        else:
            self.a_consecutivas = 1
        self.a_anterior = tipo

    def ejecutar(self):
        """Funcion principal que ejecuta el juego"""
        while True:
            bola = random.randint(0, 37)
            print(f"Bola actual: {bola}")
            self.bolas.insert(0, bola)
            print(f"Total bolas: {self.bolas}")

            if bola in self.com_apuestas_sueltas:
                self.a_ganadas += 1
                print("Ganada!")
                self.comprueba("ganadas")
            else:
                self.a_perdidas += 1
                print("Perdida!")
                self.comprueba("perdidas")

            print(f"Ganadas {self.a_ganadas} en apuestas sueltas y {self.a_perdidas} perdidas"
                  f"\n - Llevas {self.a_consecutivas} {self.a_anterior} consecutivamente.")
            time.sleep(3)


juego = Juego()
juego.ejecutar()
```

Comment: Genial, me sirve mucho para aprender, Gracias!